# I want to reduce the time in which my java script reads and stores a text file into a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The code that I have written takes around 3 minutes for file that is just 3000 lines long. But that is too long for my code. Can anyone guide me as to what am I doing wrong?

```
while((newl=bfr.readLine())!=null)
    {
        newl.trim();
        String entries[]=newl.split(",");

        String date=entries[0];

        float open=Float.parseFloat(entries[1]);
        float high=Float.parseFloat(entries[2]);
        float low=Float.parseFloat(entries[3]);
        float close=Float.parseFloat(entries[4]);
        int volume=Integer.parseInt(entries[5]);
        float adjclose=Float.parseFloat(entries[6]);
        float amt_change=close-open;
        float percent_change=(amt_change/open)*100;


        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+sname+" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, date);
        ps.setFloat(2, open);
        ps.setFloat(3, high);
        ps.setFloat(4, low);
        ps.setFloat(5, close);
        ps.setInt(6, volume);
        ps.setFloat(7, adjclose);
        ps.setFloat(8, amt_change);
        ps.setFloat(9, percent_change);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
```

This code takes a file in text format seperated by commas and enters it into a mysql database. Entries like these ::

```
2005-04-01,1215.00,1275.00,1203.00,1263.85,189900,1239.52
2005-03-31,1218.00,1235.25,1201.00,1212.60,106000,1189.26
2005-03-30,1188.00,1232.00,1174.00,1210.05,173800,1186.76
2005-03-29,1208.00,1209.95,1168.35,1184.85,196300,1162.04
2005-03-28,1210.00,1224.45,1203.00,1209.30,167500,1186.02
```

I want to reduce the time as much I can and I am a beginner. Please help.

Comment: try this: move the line "PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement" before the while loop. You don't need to prepare it again and again.

Comment: Don't forget to close your PreparedStatements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **move the `PreparedStatement` outside of the for loop**.
So the statement will be "*prepared*" only once (it means that your sql is parsed only one) and executed n times in the loop.

Additionally disable `autocommit` and commit every n insert.

```
con.setAutocommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+sname+" VALUES    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
int counter = 0;
while((newl=bfr.readLine())!=null)
{
    newl.trim();
    String entries[]=newl.split(",");

    String date=entries[0];

    float open=Float.parseFloat(entries[1]);
    float high=Float.parseFloat(entries[2]);
    float low=Float.parseFloat(entries[3]);
    float close=Float.parseFloat(entries[4]);
    int volume=Integer.parseInt(entries[5]);
    float adjclose=Float.parseFloat(entries[6]);
    float amt_change=close-open;
    float percent_change=(amt_change/open)*100;


    ps.setString(1, date);
    ps.setFloat(2, open);
    ps.setFloat(3, high);
    ps.setFloat(4, low);
    ps.setFloat(5, close);
    ps.setInt(6, volume);
    ps.setFloat(7, adjclose);
    ps.setFloat(8, amt_change);
    ps.setFloat(9, percent_change);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    counter++;

    // Try with values different of 1000 to check the best commit size.
    // It depends from the database, the hardware, the record size
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        conn.commit();
    }
}
conn.commit();   // Remember to add a final commit
```

Additionally I see that you are reading probably from a file. Check if you used a Buffered version of the input stream. You will gain some additional performance using a [Buffered stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html)

Comment: I got the time down by 30 seconds. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you have autocommit true or false?

Comment: Autocommit is enabled.

Comment: You can disable autocommit and commit at the end of the loop. If you have many records to insert commit every x insert. I update the code to show you

Comment: Yes that brings it down to 5 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work as its all happening within one transaction and so db commit is once at the end . But you can use batch update

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+sname+" VALUES       (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

while((newl=bfr.readLine())!=null)
{
....
ps.setString(1, date);
ps.setFloat(2, open);
.....
preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: No always a single transaction is the best possible solution in terms of time execution. Because the OP was using an autocommit probably it is not necessary to use a single transaction. Commit every n rows it will be better in terms of time execution

Comment: Agreed.. as long as there is one transaction, its best performance, But programmatically I don't want to maintain transaction rather use all given options. That way , you don't have to specifically handle con.autocommit(false)..